# D3.js v5 Domain() not taking variable for array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

In my Angular 5 project using D3 v5, if I give the following, the code will compile:

```
let y0 = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100000]).range([this.height, 0]);
```

However, if I give the following with variable names for the upper and lower bounds of my domain, I get an error:

```
let y0 = d3.scaleLinear().domain([d3.min(data.totalCount), d3.max(data.totalCount)]).range([this.height, 0]);
```

Error: TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | or ({valueOf(): number;})[]'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | or {valueOf(): number;}.

I know that the arguments going to d3.min and d3.max are numbers, and if I provide a test array of numbers, `test = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, I get the same error.

Why is it trying to read these variables as strings? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually four [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-array/index.d.ts#L48-L66) for `d3.min()`:

```
export function min(array: ArrayLike<string>): string | undefined;

export function min<T extends Numeric>(array: ArrayLike<T>): T | undefined;

export function min<T>(array: ArrayLike<T>, accessor: (datum: T, index: number, array: ArrayLike<T>) => string | undefined | null): string | undefined;

export function min<T, U extends Numeric>(array: ArrayLike<T>, accessor: (datum: T, index: number, array: ArrayLike<T>) => U | undefined | null): U | undefined;
```

The compiler will choose the best fit for your code, which, given that you have not provided any type parameter, comes down to the first type definition. As you can see, this expects an `ArrayLike<string>` argument and returns a `string` or `undefined`. This yields the error you observed. The same obviously holds true for `d3.max()`.

Since you know your `data.totalCount` are all numbers, you can easily pass that in as the type parameter for the generic function:

```
let y0 = d3.scaleLinear().domain([
  d3.min<number>(data.totalCount), 
  d3.max<number>(data.totalCount)
]).range([this.height, 0]);
```

---

Side note not directly related to your problem: you can use [`d3.extent()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#extent) which combines `d3.min()` and `d3.max()` in a single call.

```
let y0 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent<number>(data.totalCount))
  .range([this.height, 0]);
```

Comment: It usually means you're doing something wrong if you have to pass a type argument explicitly. If this is the case here the declarations are probably incorrectly ordered.

Comment: That works. Thanks so much! The change over to v5, which my supervisor wants to use, has left a lack of a sufficient knowledge base for proper use, and the official documentation is not yet easily consumable by those new to the library.

Comment: Specifying <T> in d3.max() solves one of the problems.